# Google My Business Website URL in Multiple Languages

Tags: local-seo, multilingual, internationalization, google-local-search, google-my-business

I manage a multi-lingual website for a hostel chain with multiple locations. Each hostel is included in Google My Business with the correct address and opening hours. However, when it comes to adding the website URL for each hostel, I come up a bit short.

We are a Dutch group, with primarily Dutch clientèle, so we're currently using the Dutch URLs here (e.g. example.com/nl/hostelname). This shows in our Google Local Listing and in Google Maps, and that's great for visitors searching in Dutch. But when English-speakers search from the UK, or when German-speakers search from Germany, they still get the link to the Dutch version of the page instead of the relevant page in English or German.

I've checked if the hreflang tags are correct; they are. I've checked if users get the correct version of the page in organic results; they do. It's only the Local Listing bar on the right of the results page that's wrong.

How can I use Google My Business to get Dutch searchers to get the Dutch link, English searchers to get the English link, German searchers to get the German link, all in the Local Listing?

Comment: Here is somebody with the same question: https://moz.com/blog/how-do-you-register-for-google-local-with-multiple-languages with an example that seems to do the right thing, but no information on how to achieve it.

Comment: This article suggests that maybe you just have to create multiple listings, one for each language and Google is OK with that: http://blumenthals.com/blog/2009/08/10/local-business-center-same-listing-in-multiple-languages-is-ok/

Comment: You will need multiple addresses since Google My Business works off real local addresses. It is the address that triggers snack pack local results.

Comment: Each hostel does have its own address, but it also has a detail page in three languages; so each location has one address but three URLs. I've thought about the redirection once on the site, but that's a separate question to how Google My Business should be configured.